# Display single column wise record for multiple row wise records

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle database for my task below.

I have a table in which the data is as below -

```
 ID      SSN
 -------------
 10       A
 20       A
 10       B
 20       B
 30       B
 20       C
```

Now, I want to display these records in the below format -

```
 SSN      ID_10_Indicator     ID_20_Indicator    ID_30_Indicator
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 A            Y                      Y                 N
 B            Y                      Y                 Y
 C            N                      Y                 N
```

I am using below query -

```
select ssn, 
(case when ID = '10' then 'Y' else 'N') as ID_10_Indicator, 
(case when ID = '20' then 'Y' else 'N') as ID_20_Indicator,
(case when ID = '30' then 'Y' else 'N') as ID_30_Indicator
from table1
group by ssn, 
(case when ID = '10' then 'Y' else 'N'),
(case when ID = '20' then 'Y' else 'N'),
(case when ID = '30' then 'Y' else 'N')
```

But I am not getting unique rows for SSN. Instead I am getting records as below -

```
 SSN      ID_10_Indicator     ID_20_Indicator    ID_30_Indicator
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 A            Y                      N                 N     
 A            N                      Y                 N
 B            Y                      N                 N
 B            N                      Y                 N
 B            N                      N                 Y
 C            N                      Y                 N
```

Please suggest. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ssn, 
  NVL (MAX (CASE ID when '10' then 'Y' else null end ),'N') as ID_10_Indicator, 
  NVL (MAX (CASE ID when '20' then 'Y' else null end ),'N') as ID_20_Indicator, 
  NVL (MAX (CASE ID when '30' then 'Y' else null end ),'N') as ID_30_Indicator
from table1
group by ssn
;
```